# Can't hide the keyboard with shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"אבגדהוזחטיכלמנסעפצקרשתףץםן"] invertedSet];

    // max charcters
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    if (newLength > 14)
        return NO;

    // allow backspace
    if (range.length > 0 && [string length] == 0) {
        return YES;
    }
    // do not allow . at the beggining
    if (range.location == 0 && [string isEqualToString:@"."]) {
        return NO;
    }
    if ((range.location > 0) && (([[textField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((range.location -1), 1)] isEqualToString:@"ף"]) || ([[textField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((range.location -1), 1)] isEqualToString:@"ץ"]) || ([[textField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((range.location -1), 1)] isEqualToString:@"ם"]) || ([[textField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((range.location -1), 1)] isEqualToString:@"ן"])))   
    {
        return NO;
    }

    // set the text field value manually
    NSString *newValue = [[textField text] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    newValue = [[newValue componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    textField.text = newValue;
    // return NO because we're manually setting the value
    return NO;
}
```

I just want to do when you click on <kbd>Return</kbd> the keyboard will disappear. I can't do that. where to add it and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to hide the keyboard after tapping the `return` key add the following to your code:

```
if ([string isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This helped me out with a different question. I forgot to allow the return key when filtering out UISearchBar text.

Answer (score 3):

in the delegate method of UITextField textFieldShouldReturn use :-

```
[yourTextField resignFirestResponder];
```

Also implement the UITextFieldDelegate in your class and set the delegate in viewDidLoad as :-

```
yourTextField.delegate=self;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an IBAction and connect it with with your TextField view.

```
-(IBAction)doneEditing:(id)sender
{
     [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Choose event *Did end on Exit* while connecting to File's Owner.